# how to apply implicit conversion for implicit parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to implicitly convert Connection to JDBC Connection for implicit connection parameter in SQL method parameter. I have this code, which throw compilation error.

```
class JDBCConnection

class Connection(val connection: JDBCConnection)
object Connection {
  implicit def Connection2JDBCConnection(connection: Connection) = connection.connection
}

object DB {
  def withTransaction[A](block: (Connection => A)) = block(new Connection(new JDBCConnection))
}

object Main {
  def SQL(query: String)(implicit connection: JDBCConnection) = println("SQL:" + query)

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    DB.withTransaction { implicit connection =>
      SQL("Hello world")
    }
  }
}



Error:(20, 10) could not find implicit value for parameter connection: JDBCConnection
      SQL("Hello world")
         ^
Error:(20, 10) not enough arguments for method SQL: (implicit connection: JDBCConnection)Unit.
Unspecified value parameter connection.
      SQL("Hello world")
```

How can I fix this?

I tried to use a parameter as an implicit but still get a compilation error

```
class Connection(val connection: JDBCConnection)
object Connection {
  implicit def Connection2JDBCConnection(implicit connection: Connection) = connection.connection
}


Error:(20, 10) not enough arguments for method SQL: (implicit connection: JDBCConnection)Unit.
Unspecified value parameter connection.
      SQL("Hello world")
         ^
Error:(20, 10) could not find implicit value for parameter connection: JDBCConnection
      SQL("Hello world")
         ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implicit conversion that takes an explicit argument will only be used if the `Connection` is used explicitly. If you want it to work implicitly, make your `Connection2JDBCConnection` take an `implicit connection: Connection`.

Comment: I tried to use a parameter as an implicit but still get a compilation error

Comment: Looking at your code, do you need to import the implicit method? Also, what's the definition of `DB.withTransaction`?

Comment: I have all the code in a single file, all of the code is given at the beginning of the question. I want to wrap a standard JDBCConnection still be able to implicitly convert it to a standard JDBCConnection

Comment: The problem is just that the implicit method is not in scope. If I add `import Connection._` just before `Main` then it works.

Comment: Thank you, it works!!! You could not give me a link where I could learn more about the scope?

Comment: See "Where do implicits come from?" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits/5598107#5598107